# Kernel Panic after diy repair

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, repair, kernel-panic

I exchanged the broken screen of a MBP7,1 with the screen of a MB6,1.
Upgraded the ram to 8gb and switched to ssd, then installed osx 10.9. 
Reseted the PRAM and SMC. Everything went pretty well !

But now the MBP restarts randomly, having KP. I don't have the installation DVD, no AHT

I don't know if the KP are due to the screen replacement, RAM, SSD or if they are prior to the modifications i made (MBP was in pretty bad shape)

"Spinlock acquisition timed out" seems to be related to graphics (no surprise), but what can i do now !? Do you have any idea !?

Here is the KP report :

```
Anonymous UUID:       xoxoxo

Tue Jan 21 20:09:11 2014
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff800e8375ca): "Spinlock acquisition timed out: lock=0xffffff800ee8a528, lock owner thread=0xe59918c16, current_thread: 0xffffff801fb65e30, lock owner active on CPU 0xffffffff, current owner: 0xe59918c16"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2422.1.72/osfmk/i386/locks_i386.c:365
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff80fa71bed0 : 0xffffff800e822f69 
0xffffff80fa71bf50 : 0xffffff800e8375ca 
0xffffff80fa71bf90 : 0xffffff800e8378c8 
0xffffff80fa71bfb0 : 0xffffff800e8d6aa7 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13B42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x000000000e600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800e800000
System model name: MacBookPro7,1 (Mac-F222BEC8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 512307135273
last loaded kext at 249847086765: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f908f9000, size 65536)
last unloaded kext at 310345579438: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f908f9000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.3fc1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.3.5
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.3.5
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBOHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.3fc1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.NVSMU  2.2.9
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro7,1, BootROM MBP71.0039.B0E, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 2.66 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.62f7
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 320M, NVIDIA GeForce 320M, PCI, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341344758334D314131303636433720
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D5341344758334D314131303636433720
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Samsung SSD 840 Series, 250.06 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: Just an idea: disconnect the replacement screen, and connect the MBP to an external monitor instead?

Comment: What kind of SSD?